# How to understand dictionary item comparison?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code:

```
max({1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"})
```

It returns 3.

I wonder what is the rule here? Function max() operates on a dictionary, how does the comparison work on a dictionary? So the item comparison is to compare their keys?

Where can I find the explanation in the language spec?

Comment: Yes, it is maximum of keys. If you simply iterate over a dictionary, you are iterating over its keys.

Comment: Iterating a dictionary yields its keys. `3` is the highest key.

Comment: Instances of `dict` have the method `__iter__`. That allows you to use `for k in mydict`. That's what makes `dict` iterable. That's what `max` uses to do its magic.